# Certificate problem starting Kestrel ASP.NET server - Windows 10, C#, VS2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, kestrel-http-server

My ASP.NET server was running fine on Friday. Today (Monday) I can't even start it. Error is:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I have tried `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` many times to no avail. Each time it gives me the prompt to trust the certificate, each time with a different thumbprint.

[image: Confirmation prompt to trust dev certificate]

... but nothing changes, the server still fails with the same error message. `dotnet dev-certs https --check` just says `No valid certificate found.` I have tried `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` which claims to succeed (but does not display any prompts), then `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` but still the same error when I start the server.

I have tried looking in the certificate manager in control panel (certmgr.msc) because doing so seemed to help someone else (on a different site) to solve the same error, but I have to admit I am none the wiser for having looked. Here's what shows up under Personal:

[image: screenshot of personal certificates in certmgr]

I *have* discovered that the server runs fine through IIS, running using the IIS profile from Visual Studio 2019. Ok, I could go adapt the client code to talk to a different TCP port, OR learn how to change the IIS server port (launchSettings.json right?).. but I would rather understand what has actually broken here, and learn how to fix it properly.

In case it helps, my Startup.Configure() says:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // for options and correct order, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

So:

1. How do I get a dev certificate into the default certificate location (wherever that is??) in a way that actually works? <-- my preferred fast solution today :/
2. Or, how do I create a dev certificate myself, and how do I tell my server where to find it?
3. Or, how do I make a real certificate (from my organisation's "official" certificate??) and then how do I use that to get client and server to actually check it, for good security? <-- my goal eventually, but I don't currently know enough yet to be able to do this - currently, my security comes from running client and server on a separate network.

Comment: Certificate need to be installed in both the machine and user certificate stores (in the registry).  The date of the certificate may also be expired.  When using HTTPS TLS is used for the authentication. Client specifies the version of TLS that is going to be used and the server sends a certificate block with a list of the names of the certificate that can be used.  The client then looks up the name of the certificate(s) to find a certificate to use.  the client also has to be able to support the encryption mode of the certificate.  It is best to use Net 4.7.2 and use operating System for TLS.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. I'm using .NET Core 3.1 because that's what VS2019 chose for me when I created the project (about 9 months ago now). Should I upgrade? If so, how? And why does this happen on the one machine I want to run the server on, but has never happened to me on my normal development machines?

Comment: Core 3.1 has many bugs.  Download latest : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1  the left column is what you using to compile, right column is the run time which gets install on deploy machine

Comment: Ok, I have installed those updates… still no difference. :(

Comment: How do I ensure the certificate is in both machine and user stores? (How do I check?) If it's expired, how do I fix this? How do I tell it to use the OS for TLS?

Comment: It looks like in the Certificate Manager you have on expired certificate.  You can download for free a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and view the TLS blocks.  The TLS blocks will show version of TLS and one of the blocks from the server to client will contain a list of certificate names.  See following for enabling OS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what finally worked for me.

The problem was that although the Certificate Manager was not showing any expired ASP.NET certificates, the Certificate Manager was only looking at the local machine store, not the user store.

I went to the Management Console (`mmc` from command line) and added a Snap-in for Certificates, for current user.

When I then ran that, I found a whole bunch of ASP.NET certificates under Personal / Certificates AND Trusted Root Certification Authorities / Certificates, some of them expired.  I deleted all of them.

I then ran `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` again, and then my server started. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete all certificates issued for localhost, best way how to do it is with this Powershell script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser -Recurse `
| Where { $_.PSISContainer -eq $false } `
| Where { $_.Issuer -match 'localhost' } `
| Remove-Item;

 Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse `
| Where { $_.PSISContainer -eq $false } `
| Where { $_.Issuer -match 'localhost' } `
| Remove-Item
```

After that you will be sure that all certificates issued for localhost are gone.

Then run

```
dotnet dev-certs https
```

That's it!